# "$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop logs" command doesn't work

Tags: hadoop

I have a Single Node Cluster setup, with `hadoop 2.4.0`. When I executed:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop logs application_*
```

It gives this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class logs
```

I had a multi-node cluster setup working, but i needed to test something in Single Cluster mode, so I switched everything back to single cluster mode. Maybe it's for that reason that I have some configuration problem here. Maybe I'm forgetting something.

My `job-history-server` logs are here, in case that someone will want to take a look:

```
2015-09-25 21:18:14,316 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2015-09-25 21:18:15,195 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2015-09-25 21:18:15,304 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: JobHistory Init
2015-09-25 21:18:16,076 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Perms after creating 504, Expected: 504
2015-09-25 21:18:16,132 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Perms after creating 493, Expected: 1023
2015-09-25 21:18:16,133 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Explicitly setting permissions to : 1023, rwxrwxrwt
2015-09-25 21:18:26,293 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Initializing Existing Jobs...
2015-09-25 21:18:26,316 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.CachedHistoryStorage: CachedHistoryStorage Init
2015-09-25 21:18:26,363 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
2015-09-25 21:18:26,377 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 10033
2015-09-25 21:18:26,443 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2015-09-25 21:18:26,514 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2015-09-25 21:18:26,514 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: JobHistoryServer metrics system started
2015-09-25 21:18:26,522 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2015-09-25 21:18:26,530 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Starting expired delegation token remover thread, tokenRemoverScanInterval=60 min(s)
2015-09-25 21:18:26,531 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2015-09-25 21:18:26,661 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2015-09-25 21:18:26,665 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLog: Http request log for http.requests.jobhistory is not defined
2015-09-25 21:18:26,678 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added global filter 'safety' (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter)
2015-09-25 21:18:26,681 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context jobhistory
2015-09-25 21:18:26,681 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context logs
2015-09-25 21:18:26,681 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context static
2015-09-25 21:18:26,685 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: adding path spec: /jobhistory/*
2015-09-25 21:18:26,685 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: adding path spec: /ws/*
2015-09-25 21:18:26,697 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Jetty bound to port 19888
2015-09-25 21:18:26,697 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2015-09-25 21:18:26,811 INFO org.mortbay.log: Extract jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/giraph-examples-1.1.0-for-hadoop-2.4.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/webapps/jobhistory to /tmp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_19888_jobhistory____.djq1tw/webapp
2015-09-25 21:18:28,196 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:19888
2015-09-25 21:18:28,197 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps: Web app /jobhistory started at 19888
2015-09-25 21:18:28,552 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps: Registered webapp guice modules
2015-09-25 21:18:28,596 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
2015-09-25 21:18:28,608 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 10020
2015-09-25 21:18:28,641 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl: Adding protocol org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.HSClientProtocolPB to the server
2015-09-25 21:18:28,641 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 10020: starting
2015-09-25 21:18:28,641 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2015-09-25 21:18:28,647 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryClientService: Instantiated MRClientService at jose-ubuntu/127.0.0.1:10020
2015-09-25 21:18:28,647 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.logaggregation.AggregatedLogDeletionService: Log Aggregation deletion is disabled because retention is too small (-1)
2015-09-25 21:18:28,648 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2015-09-25 21:18:28,656 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 10033: starting
2015-09-25 21:18:56,540 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: History Cleaner started
2015-09-25 21:18:56,551 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: History Cleaner complete
2015-09-25 21:21:26,535 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 21:24:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 21:24:26,741 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobSummary: jobId=job_1443226692984_0001,submitTime=1443227034998,launchTime=1443227041052,firstMapTaskLaunchTime=1443227043269,firstReduceTaskLaunchTime=0,finishTime=1443227055272,resourcesPerMap=512,resourcesPerReduce=512,numMaps=1,numReduces=1,user=hduser,queue=default,status=FAILED,mapSlotSeconds=9,reduceSlotSeconds=0,jobName=word count
2015-09-25 21:24:26,741 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Deleting JobSummary file: [hdfs://hdnode01:54310/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done_intermediate/hduser/job_1443226692984_0001.summary]
2015-09-25 21:24:26,832 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Perms after creating 504, Expected: 504
2015-09-25 21:24:26,833 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Moving hdfs://hdnode01:54310/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done_intermediate/hduser/job_1443226692984_0001-1443227034998-hduser-word+count-1443227055272-0-0-FAILED-default-1443227041052.jhist to hdfs://hdnode01:54310/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done/2015/09/25/000000/job_1443226692984_0001-1443227034998-hduser-word+count-1443227055272-0-0-FAILED-default-1443227041052.jhist
2015-09-25 21:24:26,901 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Moving hdfs://hdnode01:54310/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done_intermediate/hduser/job_1443226692984_0001_conf.xml to hdfs://hdnode01:54310/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done/2015/09/25/000000/job_1443226692984_0001_conf.xml
2015-09-25 21:27:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 21:30:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 21:33:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 21:36:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 21:39:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 21:42:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 21:45:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 21:48:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 21:51:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 21:54:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 21:57:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 22:00:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 22:03:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 22:06:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 22:09:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 22:12:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 22:15:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 22:18:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 22:21:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 22:24:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 22:27:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 22:30:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 22:33:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 22:36:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 22:39:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 22:42:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 22:45:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 22:48:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 22:51:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 22:54:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 22:57:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 23:00:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 23:03:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 23:06:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 23:09:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 23:12:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 23:15:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 23:18:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 23:21:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 23:24:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 23:27:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 23:30:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 23:33:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 23:36:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 23:39:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 23:42:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 23:45:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 23:48:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 23:51:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 23:54:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-25 23:57:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 00:00:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 00:03:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 00:06:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 00:09:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 00:12:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 00:15:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 00:18:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 00:21:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 00:24:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 00:27:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 00:30:26,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 11:22:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 11:25:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 11:28:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 11:31:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 11:34:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 11:37:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 11:40:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 11:43:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 11:46:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 11:49:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 11:52:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 11:55:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 11:58:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 12:01:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 12:04:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 12:07:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 12:10:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 12:13:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 12:16:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 12:19:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 12:22:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 12:25:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 12:28:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 12:31:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 12:34:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 12:37:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 12:40:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 12:43:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 12:46:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 12:49:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 12:52:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 12:55:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 12:58:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 13:01:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 13:04:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 13:07:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 13:10:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 13:13:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 13:16:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 13:19:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 13:22:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 13:25:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 13:28:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 13:31:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 13:34:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 13:37:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 13:40:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 13:43:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 13:46:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 13:49:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 13:52:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 13:55:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 13:58:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 14:01:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 14:04:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 14:07:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 14:10:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 14:13:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 14:16:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 14:19:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 14:22:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 14:25:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 14:25:49,549 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobSummary: jobId=job_1443226692984_0002,submitTime=1443288308827,launchTime=1443288317811,firstMapTaskLaunchTime=1443288320399,firstReduceTaskLaunchTime=0,finishTime=1443288331334,resourcesPerMap=512,resourcesPerReduce=512,numMaps=1,numReduces=1,user=hduser,queue=default,status=FAILED,mapSlotSeconds=7,reduceSlotSeconds=0,jobName=word count
2015-09-26 14:25:49,549 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Deleting JobSummary file: [hdfs://hdnode01:54310/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done_intermediate/hduser/job_1443226692984_0002.summary]
2015-09-26 14:25:49,667 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Perms after creating 504, Expected: 504
2015-09-26 14:25:49,667 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Moving hdfs://hdnode01:54310/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done_intermediate/hduser/job_1443226692984_0002-1443288308827-hduser-word+count-1443288331334-0-0-FAILED-default-1443288317811.jhist to hdfs://hdnode01:54310/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done/2015/09/26/000000/job_1443226692984_0002-1443288308827-hduser-word+count-1443288331334-0-0-FAILED-default-1443288317811.jhist
2015-09-26 14:25:49,804 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Moving hdfs://hdnode01:54310/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done_intermediate/hduser/job_1443226692984_0002_conf.xml to hdfs://hdnode01:54310/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done/2015/09/26/000000/job_1443226692984_0002_conf.xml
2015-09-26 14:28:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 14:31:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 14:34:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 14:37:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 14:37:49,542 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobSummary: jobId=job_1443226692984_0003,submitTime=1443288973696,launchTime=1443288978295,firstMapTaskLaunchTime=1443288980524,firstReduceTaskLaunchTime=0,finishTime=1443288991467,resourcesPerMap=512,resourcesPerReduce=512,numMaps=1,numReduces=1,user=hduser,queue=default,status=FAILED,mapSlotSeconds=7,reduceSlotSeconds=0,jobName=word count
2015-09-26 14:37:49,542 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Deleting JobSummary file: [hdfs://hdnode01:54310/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done_intermediate/hduser/job_1443226692984_0003.summary]
2015-09-26 14:37:49,557 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Moving hdfs://hdnode01:54310/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done_intermediate/hduser/job_1443226692984_0003-1443288973696-hduser-word+count-1443288991467-0-0-FAILED-default-1443288978295.jhist to hdfs://hdnode01:54310/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done/2015/09/26/000000/job_1443226692984_0003-1443288973696-hduser-word+count-1443288991467-0-0-FAILED-default-1443288978295.jhist
2015-09-26 14:37:49,563 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Moving hdfs://hdnode01:54310/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done_intermediate/hduser/job_1443226692984_0003_conf.xml to hdfs://hdnode01:54310/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done/2015/09/26/000000/job_1443226692984_0003_conf.xml
2015-09-26 14:40:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 14:43:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 14:46:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 14:49:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 14:52:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-09-26 14:55:49,517 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but `logs` doesn't exist as a command.

The available commands for `hadoop.sh` are:

```
  fs                   run a generic filesystem user client
  version              print the version
  jar <jar>            run a jar file
                       note: please use "yarn jar" to launch
                             YARN applications, not this command.
  checknative [-a|-h]  check native hadoop and compression libraries availability
  distcp <srcurl> <desturl> copy file or directories recursively
  archive -archiveName NAME -p <parent path> <src>* <dest> create a hadoop archive
  classpath            prints the class path needed to get the
  credential           interact with credential providers
                       Hadoop jar and the required libraries
  daemonlog            get/set the log level for each daemon
  trace                view and modify Hadoop tracing settings
```

So, I'm guessing you were looking for `deamonlog`?

Comment: I'm trying to obtain logs from a finished application, that's why i'm using the application id. I believe that i'm confusing with yarn, because this works `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/yarn logs -applicationId <applicationId>` there